# Pandas: set var using multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"code": ["codeA",
                            "Codeb",
                            "codeB",
                            "codea",
                            "N/A",
                            "N/A"], 
                   "warehouse": [20, 
                                 30, 
                                 10,
                                 30,
                                 10,
                                 70]})
```

I need to set a variable in a column according to three conditions:

1. value = codeA
2. value = codeB
3. value is anything other than codeA or codeB = ""

Pseudocode:

```
# account for case: make case insensitive
if value REGEX '(?i)codeA':
   value = "product A"
else if value REGEX '(?1)codeB':
   value = "product B"
else
   value = ""
```

Would I use a function with `apply`?

I can do the first 2 like:

```
df['code'].replace(to_replace="(?i)CodeA", value="Product A", inplace=True, regex=True)
df['code'].replace(to_replace="(?i)CodeB", value="Product B", inplace=True, regex=True)
```

However -- I'm stuck on trying to say: "if it doesn't match either" set to "". Also wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this with an "else" clause.

NOTE: The ideal solution would account for human error in the input -- Eg., case insensitive. I do a `strip` beforehand to account for trailing and leading spaces, however.

Comment: Please update your sample to take into account different values of `code`?

Comment: @Corralien Done! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dict mapping

```
d = {'codea': 'Product A', 'codeb': 'Product B'}
df['code'] = df['code'].str.replace(' ', '').str.casefold()
df['code'] = df['code'].map(d).fillna('')
```

Output:

```
        code  warehouse
0  Product A         20
1  Product B         30
2  Product B         10
3  Product A         30
4                    10
5                    70
```

Comment: Thanks! I should've mentioned in the post, but these are input by hand. Is there a way to make the mapping case insensitive and account for human error?

Comment: Do you mean the dict or the values in dataframe? Take into account human error is another problem. You need fuzzy logic or use `difflib`

Comment: The values in the dataframe could be Eg., CodeA, codeA, CODEA. So I think making it case insensitive would be adequate.

Comment: I updated my answer. I remove all blank spaces and all case distinctions. So update the dict to take into account the new keys. Can you check it, please?

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach to setting a column value based off a mapping to another column would be to use [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
mapping = {'codeA': 'product A', 'codeB': 'product B'}
df['mapped_product'] = df.code.map(mapping)
df
```

Out

```
    code  warehouse mapped_product
0  codeA         20      product A
1  codeB         30      product B
2  codeB         10      product B
3  codeA         30      product A
4    N/A         10            NaN
5    N/A         70            NaN
```

If all you're doing is a string replace, you could do it this way:

```
df['mapped_product'] = df.code.str.replace('code', 'product ')
df
```

Out

```
    code  warehouse mapped_product
0  codeA         20      product A
1  codeB         30      product B
2  codeB         10      product B
3  codeA         30      product A
4    N/A         10            N/A
5    N/A         70            N/A
```

Comment: Those "N/A" values should be transformed to "". Thank you!